# Status bar height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

How can I get the status bar's height programmatically in Swift?

In Objective-C, it's like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height.
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Is there any problems with **Swift 2.x**:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

**Swift 3 or Swift 4**:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Make sure `UIKit` is imported

```
import UIKit
```

**In iOS 13, you will get a deprecated warning"**

> 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager
>   property of the window scene instead.

To fix this:

```
let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Comment: New syntax for Swift 3: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height`

Comment: You can omit `size` in Swift 3: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` is enough.

Comment: let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0 is returning 0 actually

Comment: @Invincible_Pain it is probably because your current window has not been loaded yet, so replace `view.window?` with `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?`

Comment: let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
 doesn't work any more

Answer (score 26):

**Updated Answer Supporting iOS 13+ and older iOS Versions for Swift 5**

```
 func getStatusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
    } else {
        statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
    return statusBarHeight
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: A little tweak, make it a static var, then access is much clearer ie. UIApplication.statusBarHeight

Comment: It is actually implemented as a global function.
Making a static var would be convenient if I wrap it up inside a class.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use:

```
struct Screen {

 static var width: CGFloat {
  return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
 }

 static var height: CGFloat {
  return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
 }

 static var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
  let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController
  return viewController!.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
 }

}
```

Then you can do:

```
Screen.statusBarHeight
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift is just a different language. The API elements are the same. Perhaps something like this:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
let height = app.statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Answer (score 4):

Reworked answer from Ibrahim :

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let window = shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first
            return window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        } 
        
        return shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with iOS 15 iPhone (iPad may need some work). The code I use which gets rid of the deprecated warning is as follows:

```
func getStatusBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
    return statusBarHeight
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its just like in Objective-C:

```
var screenStatusBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
}
```

This is included as a standard variable in:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 0):

On my swiftUI project, this worked.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView()
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            if let statusBarHeight = window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height {
            SceneDelegateDataGetter.shared.height = statusBarHeight
            }
            
            window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

class SceneDelegateDataGetter {
    static let shared = SceneDelegateDataGetter()
    
    public fileprivate(set) var height: CGFloat = 0
}
```

When use,

```
SceneDelegateDataGetter.shared.height
```

Answer (score 0):

From **Peter Suwara** and **Bobby**'s answers

Updated for **Swift 5**:

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let window = shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first
            return window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        }
        return shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
}

struct ScreenUtils {
    static var width: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
    
    static var height: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    
    static var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIApplication.statusBarHeight
    }
}
```

**Using:**

```
ScreenUtils.statusBarHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
          let statusBarManager = windowScene.statusBarManager
    else {
        return
    }

    let statusBarHeight = statusBarManager.statusBarFrame.height
    print("Status bar height is \(statusBarHeight)")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).