# How do I retrieve iOS Status Bar height in React-Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

For Android I know I can use `StatusBar.currentHeight`  but I'm not sure how to do so for iOS.

The answer to how to retrieve the size in Swift(native) has already been answered but I need this in a react native app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Status bar height in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973733/status-bar-height-in-swift)

Comment: Looks like you'd need some listener code for this, which has been kindly done here: https://github.com/jgkim/react-native-status-bar-size. You could use the methods found in `StatusBarSizeIOS.js` or just install the package.

Comment: iOS status bar has always 20px of height So you can add statically

Comment: is that height 20px for all iOS devices? Ipad, iphones alike?

Comment: 20 density pixel is the height you are looking for. 
`const style = StyleSheet.create({container: {height: 20} }). React native will adapt the dp to the right size depending on the resolution. Si it should fit for all mobile

Comment: 20 does not fit on iPhone X.

Comment: I am using 45 for iPhone X

Comment: I think this should be part of the StatusBar as a whole

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Expo you can use `Constants.statusBarHeight`.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const statusBarHeight = Constants.statusBarHeight;
```

If you're using Vanilla React Native with React Navigation you can use the following:

```
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
const statusBarHeight = insets.top;
```

See: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/#use-the-hook-for-more-control

Sample Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { useSafeAreaInsets, SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <ChildScreen />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

function ChildScreen() {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>
        {insets.top}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {Constants.statusBarHeight}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {StatusBar.currentHeight ?? 'N/A'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Output:

|  | Samsung Galaxy S10 5G | iPhone 8 Plus | iPhone 11 Pro Max | Web |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `insets.top` | 39.71428680419922 | 20 | 44 | 0 |
| `Constants.statusBarHeight` | 39 | 20 | 44 | 0 |
| `StatusBar.currentHeight ?? 'N/A'` | 39.42856979370117 | N/A | N/A | N/A |

Live code: https://snack.expo.dev/@dcangulo/statusbarheight

Comment: You really know your stuff

Answer (score 4):

You can use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-iphonex.html) that already have support of iPhone X.

Even if you don't want use this library because of some reason - you still can read source code to copy implementation in your code

Comment: React Navigation does support notch screens. Here's the [detail document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html). It says the device info can be  retrieved by [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this package, it has very good documentation.
[react-native-status-bar-height](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-status-bar-height)