# Why do safeAreaInsets return 0 for the root view of the main view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiview

I have an app with a single view controller.

This code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.view.safeAreaInsets));
```

Logs this:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Apple documentation states:

> For the view controller's root view, the insets account for the status
> bar, other visible bars, and any additional insets that you specified
> using the additionalSafeAreaInsets property of your view controller.

Why does it return 0 then? Shouldn't it return the size of the status bar? Where can I find the height of the status bar? **Where can I find the height of the app switcher at the bottom?** The app switcher is the line element that you swipe up to switch between apps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973816/6901471

Comment: What about the app switcher height at the bottom? How can I get that?

Comment: @Vulkan - where are you calling that? Running simple, single-view controller app on iPhone 13 Pro, I get `{0, 0, 0, 0}` in `viewDidLoad` (as we know, auto-layout has not done all it's work yet), and `{47, 0, 34, 0}` in `viewDidAppear` (*after* auto-layout has run its course).

Comment: I'm using the viewDidLoad. Thanks for the clarification. Didn't know that!